# PHP 'foreach' array concatenate echo

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The following will echo "12334".

However, I would like for the "12334" to be placed in a variable say $wordNumValue. 
I know it might be a simple thing, but to me it is not. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
$msg ="hello";
$arrEn = str_split($msg);
foreach ($arrEn as &$value) {
    if ($value == 'h') {
          echo "1";
        } elseif ($value == 'e') {
          echo "2";
        } elseif ($value == 'l') {
          echo "3";
        } elseif ($value == 'o') {
          echo "4";
        } else {
          echo 'NULL';
        } 
}
?>
```

Comment: If it helps you can **accept** the best answer..

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$msg ="hello";
$arrEn = str_split($msg);
$wordNumValue = "";
foreach ($arrEn as &$value) {
if ($value == 'h') {
      echo "1";
      $wordNumValue .= "1";
    } elseif ($value == 'e') {
      echo "2";
      $wordNumValue .= "2";
    } elseif ($value == 'l') {
      echo "3";
      $wordNumValue .= "3";
    } elseif ($value == 'o') {
      echo "4";
      $wordNumValue .= "4";
    } else {
      echo 'NULL';
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$msg ="hello";
$arrEn = str_split($msg);
$wordNumValue = '';
foreach ($arrEn as &$value) {
    if ($value == 'h') {
        echo "1";
        $wordNumValue .= "1";
    } elseif ($value == 'e') {
        echo "2";
        $wordNumValue .= "2";
    } elseif ($value == 'l') {
        echo "3";
        $wordNumValue .= "3";
    } elseif ($value == 'o') {
        echo "4";
        $wordNumValue .= "4";
    } else {
        echo 'NULL';
    }
}
```

But as you have many `elseif`s I, would do this instead:

```
<?php
$msg ="hello";
$arrEn = str_split($msg);
$wordNumValue = '';
foreach ($arrEn as &$value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case "h":
            $wordNumValue .= "1";
            break;
        case "e":
            $wordNumValue .= "2";
            break;
        case "l":
            $wordNumValue .= "3";
            break;
        case "o":
            $wordNumValue .= "4";
            break;
        default:
            echo 'NULL';
    }
}
echo $wordNumValue;
```

And finally I echoed `$wordNumValue` instead of echoing single numbers several times.

Answer (score 1):

You can add each string onto a variable using the `.=` assignment operator;

```
<?php
$msg ="hello";
$arrEn = str_split($msg);
foreach ($arrEn as &$value) {
    if ($value == 'h') {
          $wordNumValue .= "1";
        } elseif ($value == 'e') {
          $wordNumValue .= "2";
        } elseif ($value == 'l') {
          $wordNumValue .= "3";
        } elseif ($value == 'o') {
          $wordNumValue .= "4";
        }
}
?>
```

You don't need the final `else`. **See this,** [PHP: Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), **and this**, [PHP: String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Hemn Baker, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You  don't need to change your code , before foreach add ob_start();
and after foreach add $wordNumValue = ob_get_clean();

Comment: That is possibly the biggest sledgehammer I've ever seen to crack the smallest nut in existence.